# Laravel Eloquent returning empty when using date in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have simple model Archive, which is tight to MySQL table. Table has field date of type date, and some other fields, like id, title, description etc.

I'm getting all the desired results if making query by any other fields than date. When it comes to date, model just returns empty results.

```
$criteria = array(['prog_i','=',9], ['date','>=','2017-11-01'], ['date','<=','2017-11-11']); 
$offset = 0;

$query = Archive::where($criteria)
                    ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
                    ->skip($offset)
                    ->take(40);

$results = $query->get();
var_dump($results); 

/* object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#350 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } } 
*/
```

However if I use same query built by Laravel (from debugger) in phpMyAdmin for testing, it works perfectly fine and is returning results.

```
select * from `archive` where (`prog_id` = '9' and `date` >= '2017-11-01' and `date` <= '2017-11-11') order by `date` desc limit 40 offset 0

Showing rows 0 - -1 (4 total, Query took 0.3204 seconds.)
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: The first condition in $criteria has prog_i instead of prog_id

Comment: Your condition initially has the wrong column name. It should be `prog_id` instead of `prog_i`.

Comment: prog_i is just mistype while rewriting it for question, it's alright in original code.

Comment: have you tried a whereRaw?

Comment: I'm sorry, it turned out all suggested approaches was working. I was making query in phpMyadmin on prod db, but eloquent in dev db which didn't have such records. Wasn't careful enough

Answer (score 0):

You can try **whereDate**

```
$criteria = array(['prog_id','=',9]); 
$criteria_1 = array(['date','>=','2017-11-01'], ['date','<=','2017-11-11']); 
$offset = 0;

$query = Archive::where($criteria)
                    ->whereDate($criteria_1)
                    ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
                    ->skip($offset)
                    ->take(40)
                    ->toSql();<--- add toSql for check your query
print_r($query);
```

Comment: Same situation happens. Eloquent returns no results, using raw query in myadmin returns results as expected.

Comment: You can check generated query using toSql() and check your query

Comment: that is not the case

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$query = Archive::where('prog_id','=',9)
  ->whereBetween('date',['2017-11-01','2017-11-11'])
   ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
   ->skip($offset)
    ->take(40);
```

Comment: Same situation happens. Eloquent returns no results, using raw query in myadmin returns results as expected.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `archive` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(160) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `tape` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `prog_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `author_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `topic_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `descr` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=58013 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: Interesting ... and this? $query = Archive::where('prog_id','=',9)
  ->where('date','>=','2017-11-01') ->where('date','<=','2017-11-11')
   ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
    ->get();

Comment: I'm sorry, it turned out all approaches was working. I was making myadmin in prod db and eloquent in dev db which didn't have such records.

Comment: @Sapnix happens ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass array for multiple where, but you can internally pass conditions with a loop.

```
$query = Archive::query();
foreach($criteria as $item) {
    $query->where($item[0], $item[1], $item[2]);
}
$query->orderBy('date', 'desc')
    ->skip($offset)
    ->take(40);

$results = $query->get();
```

Comment: No, you can pass array as from documentation [link] https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses[/link]

    $users = DB::table('users')->where([
        ['status', '=', '1'],
        ['subscribed', '<>', '1'],
    ])->get();

Comment: Yes, I had just tried and got same result as yours.